# Hosting SignalR hub under two paths in Web Application Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, signalr, signalr-hub

We have a project where I would like to have an internal application use an existing customer facing website to push information back to our customers. I have created a proof of concept and it is working great. I have two hubs set up at the moment. One is used to talk to customers and one is used to talk to the internal application. I can pass the required messages back and forward. I am looking to host them under separate paths to allow me to use two different security mechanisms eg Forms Auth for the customers and Certificate Auth for the internal application.

Is this possible or is there a better way to do this? My POC is hosted on github at https://github.com/andymac4182/SignalR-Example

Comment: What do you expect from us? download your code and modify it? Or find a document for you showing how to do it?

Comment: Any help is much appreciated. I have been unable to find how to host different hubs on different URLs. The example code was there so you could see the two different Hubs that was all.
My end goal is to have one Hub using Forms Auth and another hub using Certificate Auth